# Form and controls backgroundimage not displaying on "some" computers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a weird one.  I have a C# app that has a BackgroundImage set for the form backgrounds.  And also for some button controls.   This app has been released for several months now and has been installed on about 20 or so different computers.

Just had a new customer install the app and the background images are not displaying.   Just get the default background color displayed for the forms and buttons.  This appears to be true for ALL forms and ALL controls that have a background image set.  NONE of them show up.

One wierd thing I did notice is that there are a few buttons on one form that for whatever reason I set the .Image property instead of the .BackgroundImage property.  These buttons *DO* show the image.  So this seems to only be a problem with .BackgroundImage

Computer is Win7 Home Premium.  Tried disabling their anti virus - no help.  Not sure what the heck could be causing this.   Any ideas?  Anybody?

EDIT: Here is a screen shot from my minimal test app.  This app was done totally with the VS designer (I did not write ANY code).  Just clicking on the properties, clicking the "..." button for backgroundimage and selecting a file from my hard drive to import.   The form should have a background image.  So should the button on the left.  The button on the right I set the .Image property.  All background images are the same file as you see displayed on the button that is working.

[image]

Comment: Try making a minimum-reliable-repro case first, and then showing us the code for that.

Comment: It is definitely something with THIS computer.  There is nothing weird about the code.   I just created a test program that does the same thing on the problem PC.   The code is all out of the box visual studio generated.   Created new project.  Set background image on the default Form1 to an image (using the designer).   Compiled project.  Sent .EXE over to customer computer - no background image displayed.

I never typed a single line of code for this test app and it has the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BackgroundImage won't paint if the machine reports that it is operating in high contrast mode.  A setting for users with visual impairments.  This normally has more effects, the system color scheme will change.

You could send him a test app that shows the value of [SystemInformation.HighContrast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.highcontrast.aspx).  If that's a match and the user otherwise doesn't have trouble with his eyes then he needs to get his machine fixed.

Comment: GIVE THAT MAN A SEE-GAR!   Hans - you nailed it.  That was EXACTLY what the problem was.   Their computer had a high contrast color theme set.    

Thank you for the tip.